# Is Visual Studio 2008 SP1 redistributable package available in any Windows update/service pack?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, redistributable, windows-update

If I develop my software in Visual Studio 2008 SP1, I believe my clients need Visual Studio 2008 SP1 redistributables to run it. My question is, is there a natural way they can get the redistributables by Windows update or Windows SP1/2/3 without installing the redistributables by themselves?

Comment: (assuming c++) they generally need the same or better installed, and I don't think you want to rely of your users getting the Windows Updates before installing you application.

Answer (score 0):

Your clients actually doesn't need any redistributables - only CLR (.NET Framework) installed

Comment: They *do* if the app is not .net and there is no guarantee that they have them installed or updated.